# Compare two folders and delete the files that do NOT exist in both folders in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The following compares two folders and deletes the files that exist in both folders.

```
var common = from f1 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     join f2 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     on Path.GetFileName(f1) equals Path.GetFileName(f2)
                     select f1;

        foreach (string file in common)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
```

How do I modify this to delete the files that exist in my targetDir that do not exist in my sourceDir?

Comment: Question is ambiguous. Do you mean you want to delete files that have the same name in both folders but not the same content ?

Comment: Why we need to compare if that doesn't exists in both folders?

Comment: The code you have posted will write out to the Console the file names that are in list 1 and not in list 2. NOTHING is deleted anywhere - Especially not the files that are in both.... This is confusing....

Comment: Sorry I accidentally posted the wrong code. I want to make two folders identical. My folder1 has all the files that are in folder2 but some extras. I want to delete the extra files so they contain the same content.

Comment: I find the Linq format you have you have used the most difficult and annoying to understand. do not get me wrong, Linq is very useful but in a confusing scenario like this I would rather add a few more lines of code and be able to follow it in the future rather then compacting the code. @Marshall777 has written a clean method which I would say suits what you are trying to achieve the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it (test carefully...) :

```
// List files
var sourceFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
var targetFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDir, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

// Makes path relatives so you can compare files in subdirectories
sourceFiles = sourceFiles .Select(f => new Uri(f).MakeRelativeUri(sourceDir))
targetFiles = targetFiles.Select(f => new Uri(f).MakeRelativeUri(targetDir))

// Get files from targetDir that does not exist in sourceDir
var filesToDelete = targetFiles.Except(sourceFiles);

foreach (string file in filesToDelete)
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(targetDir, file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something this:

```
list1.Where(f1 => list2.Where(f2 => f2.Name == f1.Name).Any());
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "NOT the same", but replace `f2.Name == f1.Name` with actual comparison you were looking to make

Comment: Sorry I meant to post this code:

var common = from f1 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         join f2 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         on Path.GetFileName(f1) equals Path.GetFileName(f2)
                         select f1;

            foreach (string file in common)
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
      var targetFiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
      var notExists = targetFiles.Where(p => !File.Exists(p.Replace(targetDir, sourceDir))).ToList();

      foreach (var p in notExists) {
                try {
                    File.Delete(p);
                }
                catch (Exception) {

                }
      }
```